# Verilog: Does Vivado Synthesis tool, add signals to sensitivity list automatically?

Tags: verilog, synthesis, vivado

```
module Test( input i );
 (* MARK_DEBUG = "TRUE" *) reg b;

 always @(i)
 begin
      if(i)
           b = 1'h0;
      else
           b = ~b;
 end
endmodule
```

After synthesizing this code I get the following result during Post-Synthesis-Simulation process with ModelSim simulator :

## ** Error (suppressible): (vsim-3601) Iteration limit 10000000 reached at time 20 ns.

But I have no problem with Behavioral-Simulation phase.

It seems that the Vivado adds "b" signal to the sensitivity list automatically, Isn't it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think about this module in terms of the hardware it implies.

`b` can't be implemented as a register or latch, because it's being assigned to from a combinational `always` block. However, the resulting circuit contains a combinational loop which won't stabilize on any value when `i` is 0:

[image: schematic]

Comment: Thanks for the reply. 2 other questions: 1. Do you know any books which can help me understand how to write a synthesizable code ? 2. What software did you use to make this pic ? Thanks a lot

Comment: 1) Any good Verilog text should cover this; consider [FPGA Prototyping by Verilog Examples](https://www.amazon.com/dp/0470185325) or [Digital Design and Computer Architecture](https://www.amazon.com/dp/0123944244). 2) I used [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Xilinx's synthesis engines (XST in ISE, Vivado) automatically add missing signals to the sensitivity list. No error is given, but a warning by default.

> WARNING: [Synth 8-614] signal 'my_signal' is read in the process but
>   is not in the sensitivity list